# transform tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I want to images display for cell. but this code display, only white tableview.Why? Please tell me. (I use not storyboard.)

TableCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableCell : UITableViewCell <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tableCellView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSArray *cellArray;

-(NSString *)reuseIdentifier;

@end
```

TableCell.m

```
    #import "TableCell.h"

@implementation TableCell

@synthesize tableCellView;
@synthesize cellArray;


-(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    return @"cell";
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [cellArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableCellView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    for (UIImageView *view in cell.subviews)
    {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter; // 画像サイズを合わせて貼る

    CGAffineTransform rotateImage = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); 
    imageView.transform = rotateImage; 

    [cell addSubview:imageView];
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return 220;
}

@end
```

TableViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TableCell;

@interface TableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) TableCell *tableViewCell;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *titlesArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *peopleArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *thingsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *fruitsArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arrays;

@end
```

TableViewController.m

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "TableCell.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize tableViewCell;
@synthesize titlesArray;
@synthesize peopleArray;
@synthesize thingsArray;
@synthesize fruitsArray;
@synthesize arrays;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    titlesArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"People", @"Things", @"Fruits", nil];
    peopleArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Gardener.png", @"Plumber.png", @"BusinessWoman.png", @"BusinessMan.png", @"Chef.png", @"Doctor.png", nil];
    thingsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"StopWatch.png", @"TrashCan.png", @"Key.png", @"Telephone.png", @"ChalkBoard.png", @"Bucket.png", nil];
    fruitsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Pineapple.png", @"Orange.png", @"Apple.png", nil];

    arrays = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:peopleArray, thingsArray, fruitsArray, nil];
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return [arrays count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [titlesArray objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 220;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TableCell *cell = (TableCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];

        CGAffineTransform rotateTable = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
        tableViewCell.tableCellView.transform = rotateTable;
        tableViewCell.tableCellView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableViewCell.tableCellView.frame.size.width, tableViewCell.tableCellView.frame.size.height);

        tableViewCell.cellArray = [arrays objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        tableViewCell.tableCellView.allowsSelection = YES;
        cell = tableViewCell;

    }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
TableViewController *tvc = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = tvc;
```

Comment: what is your nib name of the cell??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCell by default already has support for images. You do **not** need to to add a new UIImageView as a subview ...

So instead of this:

```
for (UIImageView *view in cell.subviews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter; // 画像サイズを合わせて貼る

CGAffineTransform rotateImage = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2); 
imageView.transform = rotateImage; 

[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

Write this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Oh, I now notice that LOTS OF OTHER STUFF is wrong with your code! Sorry to say that. Other stuff you need to change:

1. Copy this method from your TableCell to your TableViewController: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` and remove the existing one
2. DELETE the TableCell class

I see you're also doing rotation... but leave that out for now. First try to make it work and THEN worry about rotation of the image.

Can I maybe advise you to read a book on iOS development? It seems as if you don't know what you're doing at all :(

But I do like to help you out. Can you maybe put all your code on http://www.github.com and invite me as a collaborator? My username is tomvanzummeren. I can make this app work for you.

Comment: Thank you. Would you give me some more details?Where should I write? Sorry.

Comment: Yes, create an account and check in your source files. You can also ZIP and e-mail me the source at tom.van.zummeren <at> gmail.com if that's easier for you...

Comment: I see! I'll e-mail you!! wait a sec.

Answer (score 0):

your `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method might return 0. check the value of `[arrays count]`. And one more thing is you are not created `UITableViewCell` in proper way. That might be the problem too. Check this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) for creating Custom `UITableViewCell`

Answer (score 0):

Each UITableViewCell has an image support if it's style is default.

> cell.imageView.image = yourImageView.image;

You don't need to do anything else.

You can change Image settings with changing yourImageView settings if you want.